# Upper bounds on the determinant of an "almost"-Toeplitz-Hessenberg matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, upper-lower-bounds, toeplitz-matrices

I am trying to calculate an upper bound for the determinant of a matrix of the form

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & a_{n-3} & \cdots & a_{n-m+1} & a_{n-k+1}\\
a_{n} & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_{n-m+2} & a_{n-k+2}\\ 
0 & a_{n} & a_{n-1} & \cdots & a_{n-m+3} & a_{n-k+3}\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & a_n & a_{n-k+m}\end{pmatrix}$

which is an $m\times m$ upper-Hessenberg matrix, and a Toeplitz matrix but for a single column.

By Cramer's rule, the determinant of this matrix is the determinant of a Toeplitz-Hessenberg matrix (for which Trudi's formula gives a value) times one component of a solution of a linear system of equations.  But I'm just not putting the pieces together.  Please advise.

Comment: Why do you suspect that there's a nice (easily computable) upper bound?  What are you hoping to do with this upper bound?

Comment: One upper bound can be attained as follows: given any matrix $A$ and submultiplicative [matrix-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) $\|\cdot\|$, we have $\det(A) \leq \|A\|^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can't tell you, it's a state secret.  However, have you any proof of that inequality you presented?

Comment: Yes, that's an easy one: such a norm is necessarily bigger than the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue. This is a pretty standard fact; you could use Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* as a reference for it, for instance.